# Smooth, Fast Coroutines?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a bunch of Coroutines running/working fine in my game.

However, one of them is for a power meter, and here's the issue...

You press the button, the power meter uses the coroutine to start filling up the power meter.  (represented by the width of a red panel)

The goal is to make the meter fill up fast enough, as to where you can't just get "full power" every time.  However, it also has to be smooth, and look nice.

The problem I'm facing is that my coroutine is maxed out on speed, and can't go any faster, and the meter is moving too slowly.  So to "speed up" the meter, I have to use larger width increasing increments on the red panel.

It works, but, this causes 2 problems.

1. It doesn't look smooth.  (It looks choppy and jittery)
2. It misses a whole bunch of values/possibilities.    (e.g. The bar has to increase by a unit of "50" to make it fast enough to be difficult.  But that's dumb, because that makes only 12 possibilities when stopping the meter.  And there could be up to 600!)

Has anyone faced this before?  If so, what's the best approach to making a fast, but smooth power meter, that can still hit a full range of value possibilities?

Thanks,
Ben

Here is my Code:

```
public static IEnumerator StartPitchMeter(Player.Guy guy, float duration)
{

    var dur = 0.01f;

    do
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(dur);

        PlayerControls.PitchMeter += 50f;

        if (PlayerControls.PitchMeter > 600) PlayerControls.PitchMeter = 0f;

        PlayerControls.pitchMeter.sizeDelta = new Vector2(PlayerControls.PitchMeter, 50);

    } while (!PlayerControls.stopPitch);

}
```

Comment: Post the code for your power meter coroutine.

Comment: At what framerate is your game rendering?

Comment: I believe I am running at the standard framerate?  I don't know much about framerates.  Would it be a good idea to mess with the timescale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a coroutine to update something for graphical purposes, you want to update on every available render frame (same as how often `Update` methods are called). So, instead of waiting for a set amount of time to pass, use `yield return null` and then move the meter according to `Time.deltaTime`, the time elapsed since the last frame in seconds. In this case, you can multiply `Time.deltaTime` by how many units per second you would like the meter to fill:

```
public static IEnumerator StartPitchMeter(Player.Guy guy, float duration)
{

    do
    {
        yield return null;

        // Fill 50 units per second.
        float fillThisFrame = Time.deltaTime * 50f;

        PlayerControls.PitchMeter += fillThisFrame;

        if (PlayerControls.PitchMeter > 600) PlayerControls.PitchMeter = 0f;


        PlayerControls.pitchMeter.sizeDelta = new Vector2(PlayerControls.PitchMeter, 50);
        // Not sure what the 50 is doing here so it might be this instead:
        // PlayerControls.pitchMeter.sizeDelta = new Vector2(PlayerControls.PitchMeter, fillThisFrame);

    } while (!PlayerControls.stopPitch);

}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'm using a coroutine because I want it to be consistent.  (no matter how fast the computer is)  Let me know if I'm insane/off base there.

Comment: @Penjimon In addition to this you can have a look at the script reference for Mathf.SmoothDamp. It should help solve your jitter problem.

Comment: @Penjimon Consistency is achieved with the combination of per-frame updates (typically using `yield return null`) and adjusting the animation based on how long the last from took to process (using `Time.deltaTime`)

Comment: @Penjimon Does this answer not solve your problem of stuttering? I'm not sure what to make of your comment

Comment: @Ruzihm Yes, the answer gets as close to solving the problem as possible, but it's still slower than I hoped for.   As for my comment, "Immersive" was close, because since computers are all different speeds, you have to use Time.DeltaTime, or the speed will be inconsistent across the all the different machines.  That's what I was trying to prevent with my initial "Time Hacking".

Comment: @Penjimon If it's slower than you need, then increase the constant factor of `fillThisFrame` to something greater than `50f`.

Comment: @Penjimon I added some clarification to the answer on how `Time.deltaTime * 50f` means "fill the meter 50 units per second". That should help you select an appropriate constant factor.